# Unable to select test methods while adding a Test Project in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

Iam trying to create a new test project. I remember selecting the names of functions while creating the test project so that system automatically creates Test Methods for those.

But Iam unable to find those options in VS2010 now . Am I missing some thing ?
I go for Add New Project-> C#-> Test-> Test Project

One more doubt that I have is that , the test project that I create like this is Nunit or MSTest ? I do not see any reference to any nunit dlls but Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Nor I do see any option for nUnit/MSTest ..

Any help ?
Thank you so much for going through my doubt ?

Comment: You should test behavior, not methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new test project, do like this: Right click the class you want to test and select "Create Unit Tests..." in the context menu.

The project that is created is MSTest (or "Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework"), not NUnit.

Comment: Thanks .. So it used to be nunit with VS2008. and MSTest with VS2010..rt ?

Comment: Nunit is an open source test framework.You can refer the dll in your test project. VSTS based on MSTest framework. So you will not get NUnit in any of the version.